# PHP SSH session is not killed

Tags: php, ssh, ssh2-exec

When we use `ssh2_connect`, ssh session is created. After all the work is done, I do

```
ssh2_exec($con, 'exit;');
unset($con);
```

This is a continuous process (ssh connections are established and closed from code).
After 2/3 days I find, further ssh session (even tried manually from terminal), are refused. So it is more likely SSH sessions are not killed properly.

Please guide me how can I exit PHP session in a neat and clean way so that never ssh2_connect fails in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$blah=ssh2_exec($con, 'exit;');
....
fclose($blah);
```

Comment: Do I need to call unset($con);Can I have code something like $blah=ssh2_exec($con, 'exit;');fclose($blah);unset($con). Or do you suggest unset($con) is not required at all.

Comment: @Kamal Nope,you dont need to call unset.